# How do I handle exceptions in Python without blocking execution?

Tags: python

Let us say within my (long) program with multiple classes/modules/files, I have a division by zero error that I did not deal with in a `try ... except` block. This error, as you know, will block my program.

Is there a way to log into a file this error I forgot to handle in order to correct my program later when I check the errors logfile ?

Comment: To maintain log for it , at least you have to wrap your code around `try except` block. Otherwise your code will crash.

Comment: @Fledgling: Thank you. I admit that my program will crach. But is there an idea on how to save into a file the error that my program encountered so as when I check my errors.log file I will see why and where my code crashed ?

Comment: Do you want to "restart" the application in case of one of these? I can update an answer once you provide clarity?

Comment: I can restart the application, yes (in python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/Catch/Finally not preferable?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    #my code
  catch:
    exc_logger.exception('Guys, can we fix this?')
```

If you want to get fancy and use/abuse language features, you can place a error context catcher within your code:

```
class ExceptionRecorder(object):
  def __init__(self, exc_logger):
    self.exc_logger = exc_logger

  def __enter(self):
    pass

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    if exc_value:
      self.exc_logger.error('Program terminated with the following: ', exc_value)

    return True
```

and in your main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  with ExceptionRecorder(logger.getLogger('oh_no')):
    #run the program code here
```

Take a look at how [Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) work, specifically the [`__exit__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

Comment: I checked  object.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) you showed me. it needs an exception as a parameter. But that is my problem: in the case I forgot to raise an exception around that code, I have no exception to pass as a parameter to this function. My aim is to save the error that occured inside an object/class into an errors.log file.

Comment: @begueradj If you don't catch an exception it will flow all the way to the top and crash your program. The exception will contain all the information needed to record where, when, and how the exception occurred (in general, YMMV.)

Comment: I know how to deal with an exception. I think no one read my question and my answers that repeated my question.

Comment: @begueradj "Correct my program" is not a clear enough action. What does "correct my program" mean? Does it mean, "later on I can fix the code and I have a record of what went wrong?" Does it mean, "restart the application?" Does it mean, "code that self-diagnoses the problem and writes code so that it won't happen again?"

Comment: by "correct my program", I mean "later on I can fix the code and I have a record of what went wrong"